# Merge data from 2 messages in 1 entity

Tags: jpa, concurrency, jms, weblogic

I have a JMS-Queue with multiple consumers on multiple cluster-nodes. I'm getting messages from different senders. There may be multiple messages with informations for only one entity. The entities need to be persisted with jpa. When a message for an entity is received the entity may or may not already exist in database.

The problem raises when 2 consumers process a message for the same entity at the same time. Both consumers try to find the entity on the database. Because there is no entity found, both try to insert the entity instead of updating the existing one. So the faster one wins and the other one ends up in an exception (because of a unique key constraint on the table).

I thought about a nasty solution by doing some try-/catch-around a flush-call. But I use container-managed transactions and there is still a gap between flush and the end of the transaction.

Second thought was about the difference between merge and persist. But even if it may work with merge, it would result in overwriting existing data.

I think this has to be a very common challenge, but I couldn't find a clean solution till now. Maybe I'm thinking in the wrong direction.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ben, if you bracket the 'test' and insert in the same DB transaction, the second consumer should never get into the state where test succeeds but inserts fails. Are you using explicit transaction begin and commit ?

Comment: 'test' and insert happen in the same transaction. But if transaction in consumer 1 is not yet commited, its changes are not visible for consumer 2. So if transaction 1 is commited after 'test' in consumer 2, the problem occours. At least I think i happens like this.

Comment: HI Ben, if your DB transaction is working as expected, consumer 2 will be blocked while consumer 1 is doing test and insert. How are you starting and stopping transactions ?

Comment: Hi Axel. Transactions are started and stopped by the container (EJB). I think this is a question of database isolation level. Should be 'read committed' in my case. And therefore, 'phantom read' is permitted ([link](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-transaction-isolation-levels)). I think this is what happens here? There is no lock over the whole table in case of an ìnsert`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Hi Ben, yes, agreed. with this isolation level you can get into trouble. I think what you are doing is parallelizing a (currently) non-parallelizable algorithm. Is it possible to pre-create all entities on startup ? And what exactly would it mean to have an update 1 on entity A with price 100 and later an update 2 on same entity with price 102 ? Since you are 'parallelizing' it with these consumers, update 2 could overtake update 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to pre-create entities at startup, because they are 'defined' at runtime. About your second question: In fact, every message adds child-entities to the root-entity. The first call has to create the root-entity. So no value is overwritten by a second message, there are only added values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JMS provider has support for message groups you could put all the messages for a particular entity into a single group and that way all the messages in the same group would go to same consumer and be processed serially rather than concurrently thereby avoiding the race condition.

Typically message group support is implemented so that it doesn't matter whether or not the messages come from the same producer just as along as there is a way to identify the group ID deterministically from the message content. For example, if you were sending messages with data to be stored in a database then the group ID could be set to the primary key. Messages with the same primary key would therefore be in the same group and would be consumed by the same consumer.

Grouped messages are consumed as soon as they are available on the queue just like normal messages. The only difference between normal and grouped messages is that they always go to the same consumer. Whether or not a group is "complete" is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think this will work, because I've different producers and they don't know each other. So this is not achievable at producer side, I think. And if this is done at queue/consumer side, how to know if a group is "complete"? When to start with processing?

Comment: Oh, now I understand. I'm using Weblogic. First I had a look at Unit-of-Work-functionality, but I think there needs to be an incremental sequence and an "end"-message. But there is also a Unit-of-Order-functionality, which doesn't need a sequence, but works with creation date of the message. That should fulfill my need. Will give it a try next week. Thanks for the pointer in the right direction!